# Relationship count duplicating in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

i am trying to resolve this query since last three days. But unable to find a proper solution. I have asked the question before. Than i reduced the query to one number to see whats the problem. Issue is in the end i received 7 nodes with two way relationships. which means total 17 relationships for 7 nodes. in graphical view it is 14 but in count table the relationships count is 28. Which means it doubles in count. for more clarification i am attaching the images and query.

```
START n= node(2679)
MATCH p=(n)-[:CALLS]-(a),(n)-[:CALLS]-(b),(a)-[:CALLS]-(n)-[:CALLS]-(b)
WITH a,b,n,p
OPTIONAL MATCH q=(a)-[:CALLS]-(b),(b)-[:CALLS]-(a) with a,b,n,p,q
RETURN q;
```

[image: Graphical View of query]

For the same data when i count the relationships with distinct clause while using the query

```
START n= NODE(2679)
MATCH p=(n)-[:CALLS]-(a),(n)-[:CALLS]-(b),(a)-[:CALLS]-(n)-[:CALLS]-(b)
WITH a,b,n,p
OPTIONAL MATCH q=(a)-[:CALLS]-(b),(b)-[:CALLS]-(a) WITH a,b,n,p,q
RETURN COUNT (DISTINCT p ) as ALL_PATHS,
COUNT (DISTINCT q) AS Backyard_Paths
ORDER BY Given_Numbers ASC;
```

[image: Resultant of count clause]

I can not check each values as my data is in millions. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your goal with the query? Is it to return each path (only once) between the centre node and other 7 nodes?

Comment: my goal is to get the count of `p` relationships for each number and count of the `q` relationships.

Comment: Does the first picture depict your complete sample data set? (i.e. hub and spoke with bi-directional relationships between each outer node and the hub)

Comment: Thanks Dave, any idea why i am having the duplicates. what s wrong with the query ??

Comment: just like @cybersam said in your other question, your duplication is due to the fact that your queries lack direction. so you get a match going both ways (i.e. same match but once starting one way and once starting the other)

Comment: Thanks Dave, i change the query and it is working according to my requirements. Thanks alot

Comment: Dave, with the arrows query is taking so much time. results appeared in 338470 ms. which is approximately 338 sec.

Comment: what is the logic behind your query?  why do you have n-a, n-b and a-n-b in the first match? i.e. why aren't you just start with something like this... `start n = node(2679) match n-[:CALLS]-(b) return n, count(b)`? As it stands your query just returns a cartesian product.  I think you want back 7 not (2 * 7) * (2 * 7) - true?

Comment: hi Dave, idea is simple. i want to perfrom the query like` fof` or something like, me`(n)` calls to my different friends `a`and `b` which are `p` paths or p-relationships. Than i want to see and count the relationships when my friends call each other. which is `q` path

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this get you what you are after?

```
// find yourself and all of the friends that you call
match (me:Node {name:'center'})-[:CALLS]->(friend)

// put all of your friends in a collection
with me, collect(friend) as friends

// then with the collection of your friends
// find out which of your friends they call
unwind friends as one_friend
match one_friend-[r:CALLS]->(another_friend)

// only match other friends that are in your friends list
where another_friend in friends
and not one_friend = another_friend
return count(r)
```